# Wordpress rest api return users who have not created a post

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

Using the wordpress rest api, is there a way to return all users, regardless of whether they have created a post or not. I am aware that I can do that if authenticated as an admin user, but I need to be able to do it as a standard user (subscriber)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by adding this filter in your `functions.php` file.

```
add_filter( 'rest_user_query', 'prefix_remove_has_published_posts_from_wp_api_user_query', 10, 2 );
/**
 * Removes `has_published_posts` from the query args so even users who have not
 * published content are returned by the request.
 *
 * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/
 *
 * @param array           $prepared_args Array of arguments for WP_User_Query.
 * @param WP_REST_Request $request       The current request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
function prefix_remove_has_published_posts_from_wp_api_user_query( $prepared_args, $request ) {
    unset( $prepared_args['has_published_posts'] );

    return $prepared_args;
}
```

Source: [WP Users Endpoint doesn't return all users](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/2300#issuecomment-299202391)

Comment: @Ruben Pauwels when I add this code no users are returned at all.